# Bootstrap 3.1 - How to have list item text line up on the left, AND centered in column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Not sure how to describe this exactly but here goes:

I have a **3 column design**, and there is a **list of items in each of the columns**.

**I need to have:**

**1)** Each column's list items must aligned so that the **left side of each word lines up**

**2)** Each **list itself must be centered within its column**. (This of course means that list items on their own won't necessarily be dead center inside their respective column)

**I would prefer a CSS solution without javascript/jQuery.**

I have an example of bootstrap code that I am working on here to help explain what doesn't work for me:

http://bootply.com/112003

The first row is what happens when the text is centered within each column. **Condition 2 passes, condition 1 fails**.

The second row is what happens when I divide up each of the three colums into 3 subcolumns. Condition 1 passes, but condition 2 fails. This is subtle. While each list item is in the center subcolumn, overall the list isn't in the dead center of that column. (Imagine the list is one item if that helps think about the problem.)

Thanks to anyone who can try to help me out. This one is driving me a little bit crazy :)

Comment: So you actually want the list itself not to be centered but only its contents?

Comment: If I'm getting you right, you want list items to be in a horizontal line like this? - http://prntscr.com/2qr9jr
Set property display:inline; for list items to achieve this.

Comment: @jtheman - Not sure I understand you either unfortunately... If I can try to rephrase... I want that the list items must all be aligned so that the beginning of each list item lines up with every other list item. I think this is the default behaviour for lists anyway. However, what I want in addition is that if you imagine the list as one entity, I want it dead center within its column. Normally, when you center text in a block, it centers each list item in the block individually, so the list items no longer align along the beginning of the word...

Comment: @Nix - not quite. I want the list items each on a seperate line. But also the list, if viewed as one item, is in the horizontal center of the column. Normally when you center text in a block, it centers each item individually, and that breaks my requirement that the the left side of the word (i.e. the first character) lines up with the first character of the list item below it.

Comment: Do you mean like http://jsfiddle.net/NW3GK/1

Comment: Erm.. like this? http://prntscr.com/2qrpx5

Comment: Edit, updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NW3GK/2

Comment: @Nix - I think you're getting the idea of what I want, but the list is not exactly centered I think. If you will draw a bounding box around the list elements then you will see its slightly to one side. I think jtheman might have gotten a solution right now though.

Comment: @jtheman - Yeah I think that it! Was wondering if bootstrap had a text align class for that, but guess your own CSS is needed for that one.

I'll have to take a screenshot and compare if it really is dead center but it seems that way.

Thank you all for the help. I really suck at explaining things clearly so I am sorry about that...

Comment: OK, try setting `display: inline-block` to your UL, that might do the difference (without seeing your code).

Comment: @jtherman - will do. I made an image quickly for others who find this in the future (using your example) so it will be clearer what I wanted:

http://imgur.com/8os3a3M


I would have made this earlier but I don't have Photoshop on my dev machine. Had to install GIMP and struggle through it a bit..